# CustomControls: How can I update a TextBlock when my TextBlock content changes

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

If this was a usercontrol, it'd be child's play to bind it, but that won't work in a user control.

I want the TextBlock to update when the TextBox text changes.  I can set it on launch, but it doesn't change afterwards.

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _MTBGrid = GetTemplateChild("MTBGrid") as Grid;
        _previewMarkdownBlock = GetTemplateChild("PreviewMarkdownBlock") as MarkdownTextBlock;
        _inputTextBox = GetTemplateChild("InputTextBox") as TextBox;
        _previewMarkdownBlock.Text = _inputTextBox.Text;

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (String)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
```

I have tried adding a TextChanged event to the xaml, but it doesn't update. I'm not very experienced with this.

```
private void InputTB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateMarkdownBlock(this, _previewMarkdownBlock, _inputTextBox.Text);
    }
private static void UpdateMarkdownBlock(MarkdownTextBox markdownTBControl, MarkdownTextBlock markdownPreview, String newValue)
    {
        if (markdownPreview != null && newValue != null)
        {
            markdownPreview.Text = newValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not subscribe to the TextBox's `TextChanged` event and manually do the update there?

Comment: @Joe in Xaml I've tried "TextChanged="InputTB_TextChanged". 
and in the codebehind
        private void InputTB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateMarkdownBlock(this, _previewMarkdownBlock, _inputTextBox.Text);
        }
        private static void UpdateMarkdownBlock(MarkdownTextBox markdownTBControl, MarkdownTextBlock markdownPreview, String newValue)
        {
            if (markdownPreview != null && newValue != null)
            {
                markdownPreview.Text = newValue;
            }
        }

Comment: @Abort_Retry: Are you saying that the `TextChanged` event isn't raised when you edit the `TextBox`?